# How to compute $\int_{\lvert\,z\,\rvert\,=\,4}\frac{1}{z\cos(z)}\,dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How can I  compute this integral $\displaystyle{\int_{\lvert\,z\,\rvert\,=\,4}\dfrac{1}{z\cos(z)}\,dz}?$

Here $0,\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}$ points are poles for the function $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z\cos(z)}$ in $\lvert\,z\,\rvert\,\leq4.$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use the residue theorem

Comment: Compute the residue at $0,\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and you are done. The value of the integral is $2i(\pi-4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue at $z=0$ is $1$, and the residues at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $z=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ are both $-\frac{2}{\pi}$. Therefore the integral is equal to $2\pi\,i(1-\frac{4}{\pi})=2i(\pi-4)$.